# GCC allows 1-line declaring of multiple pointers, but not non-pointers, with different const qualifiers

Tags: c++, pointers, gcc, constants, variable-declaration

Given the below program, GCC (`g++`, but I *presume* the non-`std::` bits apply to C too), [as can be seen on IDEone.com](https://ideone.com/MXGrSA), behaves as follows:

- It allows declaring multiple pointers in one line, each with its own possibly different `const` qualification, which is honoured.
- It does *not* allow the same for multiple non-pointers. Instead, the `const` or lack thereof of the first variable is used for all variables declared in that line. Any further `const` keywords produce a syntax error.

My questions are therefore:

- Is this expected, correct behaviour in both pointer and non-pointer cases?
- Why, in terms of the Standardised grammar, does this difference exist?

I have searched but had no luck. I do have n3797.pdf open in front of me here, but I just don't seem to be at the required level to understand its specification of the grammar yet. :( So hopefully someone who is can assess and translate as required.

Please don't just say not to declare multiple variables in one line. I know why it's discouraged, and I try not to. FWIW, `for` loops make it tempting as a way to get a `const` end iterator - which seems possible if said iterator is a pointer, but not if it's a class. Anyway, I'm not asking for code review. The topic is why this difference exists, independent of how advisable it is to exploit it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

int main()
{
    int i{42};

    int *p1 = &i, *const p2 = &i; // OK
    std::cout << std::is_const< decltype(p1) >::value << '\n'; // 0
    std::cout << std::is_const< decltype(p2) >::value << '\n'; // 1

    int *const p3 = &i, *p4 = &i; // OK
    std::cout << std::is_const< decltype(p3) >::value << '\n'; // 1
    std::cout << std::is_const< decltype(p4) >::value << '\n'; // 0

    int const l = i, m = i; // OK
    std::cout << std::is_const< decltype(l) >::value << '\n'; // 1
    std::cout << std::is_const< decltype(m) >::value << '\n'; // 1

    //int j = i, const k = i; // error: expected unqualified-id before ‘const’
}
```

Comment: is this supposed to be tagged `C`?

Comment: Well, yes, because as I said, I _presume_ the core of it applies to C too, but I don't know how to reflect the `const` or non-`const` of the resulting variables without using `type_traits`, hence why it's written in C++.

Comment: Please don't use 1-line multi declarations.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Record timing. I try not to, in actual code - but `for` declarations are a good example of where it gets tempting. Anyway, this is a theoretical question. Did you have anything actually on topic to add?

Comment: Chapter 8 of n3797.pdf (p180-181) shows that this is OK in the grammar rules there.

Comment: Note that there is a very big difference between `int *p1, *const p2;` and `int *p1, const *p2;`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am well aware of that, and based on my experience with non-pointer variables I expected _both_ of these mixed-`const` declarations to be illegal, but the former appears not to be, so that's why I asked about it (and only it).

Comment: I see someone is trigger-happy. In what universe does asking for a breakdown of how and why the Standard specifies this qualify as "primarily opinion-based"? Even for the _why_, one should be able to read papers on, or at least logically infer, the reasons for design decisions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @JonathanLeffler pointed out:

> Chapter 8 of n3797.pdf (p180-181) shows that this is OK in the grammar rules there.

Each element of a list of declarators can be either a *noptr-declarator* or a *ptr-declarator*. The *ptr-operator* component of the *ptr-declarator* case has its own *cv-qualifier-seq opt*. But the *noptr-declarator* doesn't.

So much for the legalese, but why is it like this? Well, once I started to think about this more, it made sense: There is a distinct split between the leading typename and the list of declarators. Non-pointer declarators create variables with that exact type, which hence get the same `const`ness as it.

In contrast, pointer declarators also have their own `const`ness, separate from that of the referred type. And I think the reason each pointer in a list of declarators can have a distinct `const`ness is due to the ((in)famous) way that the *ptr-operator* binds: to variable names, not to the referred variable type.

So for code like this to ever be seen as 'equivalent' to non-pointer declarations and mean 'all of these pointers are themselves const'...

```
int* const p = &i, q = &j, r = &l;
```

...then the grammar would have to be totally different and consider the *ptr-operator* as part of the typename, not as an attribute of each variable.

But as we know, it's the latter that's true. So, given that, the presence of a *cv-qualifier-seq opt* in each *ptr-operator* component is the only way to let even **one** pointer have its own `const`ness, separate from that of the referred-to type. The fact that each other pointer in a list of declarators can have a distinct `const`ness is just a side-effect of that, since each declarator needs its own *ptr-operator* (to avoid becoming a non-pointer).

This all seems very obvious in hindsight. I guess I'm just having a slow day.

Comment: I had to quickly go check that the standard does say what I pointed out that it does say, first in the C standard (because I usually have that open) and then in the C++ standard.  The main reason that most people don't run into this as a question is that they stick to 'one variable per line' so that they never try mixing up the declarator contents as your examples do.  Mostly I stick by 'one variable per line'; when I don't, I only put identically qualified types on the line. I might sometimes use `int *x, *y, *z;` but I'd never use `int x, *y, **z;`, for example, let alone `int x, *const y;`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Sure, I don't usually. But a likely case, & why I noticed, is in `for` loops: `for (auto *it = &things[0], *const end = it + things.size(); it < end; ++it)`. Albeit obfuscating, this ensures the `end` iterator is not (A) scoped outwith the loop or (B) inc/decrementable, as I try to be obsessive about `const`-correctness. It's probably cleaner in all other ways to declare `end` outwith the `for`, but then it leaks scope. I realised that such a scoped `const end` is achievable if the iterator is a pointer, but not if it's a class; those must be non-`const`. It's all a trade-off!